# Cannot resolve method ComputeDistanceBetween

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, gps

I am working with Google Maps and supporting the Map Fragment Class. I want the program to compute the distance between two points. However, I get an error saying that I cannot resolve the method ComputeDistanceBetween. How do I fix this? (Most of the code was taken from Github).

```
public class DistanceDemoActivity extends BaseDemoActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Marker mMarkerA;
    private Marker mMarkerB;
    private Polyline mPolyline;
    private Object SphericalUtil;


    protected int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.distance_demo;
    }


    protected void startDemo() {
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-33.8256, 151.2395), 10));
        getMap().setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        mMarkerA = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.9046, 151.155)).draggable(true));
        mMarkerB = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.8291, 151.248)).draggable(true));
        mPolyline = getMap().addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true));

        Toast.makeText(this, "Drag the markers!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showDistance();
    }

   private void showDistance() {
        double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(mMarkerA.getPosition(), mMarkerB.getPosition());
        mTextView.setText("The markers are " + formatNumber(distance) + " apart.");
    }

    private void updatePolyline() {
        mPolyline.setPoints(Arrays.asList(mMarkerA.getPosition(), mMarkerB.getPosition()));
    }

    private String formatNumber(double distance) {
        String unit = "m";
        if (distance < 1) {
            distance *= 1000;
            unit = "mm";
        } else if (distance > 1000) {
            distance /= 1000;
            unit = "km";
        }

        return String.format("%4.3f%s", distance, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        showDistance();
        updatePolyline();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        showDistance();
        updatePolyline();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should probably point where most of the code was taken from or at least what part of it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SphericalUtil` is a class from the Google Maps API Utility Library and you are declaring an `Object` named SphericalUtil.

Remove this line:

```
private Object SphericalUtil;
```

Also, make sure that you are adding the Google Maps API Utility Library to your `build.gradle` following the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).